# Nightwatch function not working inside while loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, memory, nightwatch.js

I have a function that works outside of a loop. The function looks for dropdown elements, saves them to a list called elements, finds the id of the elements, checks the id with a json file which describes which dropdown to click, then it clicks the element and adds the element to a used list. However when I put it inside a while loop of unknown iterations it fails to run the function and gets stuck. I think the problem is around how javascript is allocating memory, even after I cancel code execution my node.js process keeps using memory until a GC error message appears in my console. I think it might be because Javascript is asynchronous but I don't know how to get around that. Does anyone know if this is the reason why it's not working? Is there anyway to get it working otherwise? Thanks.

### Function definition

```
function DropdownInput(testList) {

  client.keys(client.Keys.HOME) //Scroll to top of page
  //console.log('Working here #1') ************** THE FUNCTION STOPS WORKING PAST THIS POINT ************

  client.elements('xpath', '//input[@placeholder="Select"]', function (elements) { //This finds all the drop down elements on the webpage


    for (const item of elements.value) {
      client.elementIdAttribute(item['ELEMENT'], 'id', function (name) {

        var elementId = name.value
        var nextElement = JSON.stringify(testList[elementId]) //This goes through the json file and finds the input values where the json matches the webpage elements

        if (nextElement !== undefined) { //This is for handling when a page element exists but is not in the json file
          var inputValue = nextElement.split('"')[3] //This trims the brackets etc from the json file input

          var menuCss = '#' + elementId
          var dropdownCss = 'li' + '#' + elementId + '_' + inputValue


          client.waitForElementVisible(menuCss, 0, false, function (result) {
            if (result.value) {
              if (!(dropdownlist.includes(menuCss))) { //Checks that the element hasn't been clicked before
                client.moveToElement(menuCss, 15, 15) //This clicks the page element that has the same id as the json + the yes or no from the trimmedtext
                client.execute('window.scrollBy(0,200)')
                client.click(menuCss)
                client.click(dropdownCss)
                dropdownlist.push(menuCss)

                // console.log(menuCss)
                // console.log(dropdownCss)
              }
            }
          })
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```

### Code with loop

```
Then('the User populates all the fields', () => {

  dropdownlist = []

  TermsPage.getAttribute('@SubmitVersion', 'disabled', function (result) {

    while (result.value === 'true') {
      DropdownInput(testList)
    }
  })

  return TermsPage.waitForElementVisible('@SubmitVersion').click('@SubmitVersion')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with how Nightwatch command queue works
This will give will be a great place to refer
https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Understanding-the-Command-Queue

Also whenever I have such async code I use browser.perform
ref: https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Understanding-the-Command-Queue#the-perform-command